# Can I allocate an object larger than 4GB on 32bit system

Tags: c#, java, .net, memory, jvm

Assuming that there is no limit of runtime or OS. Can I allocate an object that is bigger than Virtual Address Space?

Comment: The question is bizarre: assuming that the world is completely different than it is, you can do *anything*.

Comment: I don't get it. Assuming there are no real life constraints I could fly like a bird.

Comment: Are you asking if there is not enough memory then will it go into paging?

Comment: If you take away all constraints, the question does not seem to make much sense. I guess, if you still define object as something that fits in (virtual) memory, then no. OTOH, maybe 32bit in your context does not mean a 4GB address space (see @Affe's proposed computer). Really, without limiting the question to the "real world", there is no point.

Comment: One could certainly invent a computer with a 32-bit address space that uses arbitrarily large memory word + addressable unit sizes and store as much data as you want.... the question does not make any sense without some kind of constraint :)

Comment: This question is senseless. If there is no real life constraint, there is no limit to what you could do. Sorry, but voting to close as not a real question - there's no sensible answer to this question possible IMO. Even after your edit it makes no sense.

Answer (score 10):

I'm trying to find a real question in this oddly worded question. How about these questions?

> Is there a theoretical limit to the size of an object in .NET, assuming that there is enough virtual memory space available?

Yes. The runtime does not permit a single managed object larger than 2 GB regardless of operating system.

> Is it legal in Windows to allocate a block of memory larger than the virtual memory space?

Yes. People are often surprised by this fact, but remember, virtual memory is called *virtual memory* for a reason; it's not *real memory*. Real memory is disk space.

Memory is not RAM -- that's just a fast, convenient cache on top of disk space. And memory is not virtual memory; virtual memory is just a convenient way to refer to memory. Memory is best visualized in my opinion as pages in a swap file on disk.

If you want to allocate a four billion byte block in 32 bit Windows, there's no problem; the operating system will reserve you four billion bytes on disk. You can then decide how to map that into your virtual address space; it's not all going to fit, so you're going to have to manage mapping and unmapping it yourself.  Raymond describes how to do so here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/10/211890.aspx

I'm not aware of any libraries that allow you to do operations on memory blocks that big easily from C#, but it would not be particularly difficult to write one if there isn't one available already. Frankly though I'd be inclined to go with memory mapped files (which you *can* do from C#) rather than doing the mapping myself.